# Nginx Alias Is Giving 'File not found' with Docker-Compose Containers

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, docker-compose, alias

I have two Laravel projects

- Laravel 4 `with 664 user:www-data permission`
- Laravel 5 `with 664 user:www-data permission`

**Note:** `moduletwo` is the alias being used in this virtual host to point to the Laravel 5 files.
I am trying to configure both on my local machine where the Laravel 4 is the main project and Laravel 5 will be used as an alias in Nginx virtual host.

Laravel 4 is working good and no issue with that.

But when I try to access the Laravel 5 module it says `File not found.`and **here are the logs**:

**access.log:**

```
GET `/moduletwo/index.php/LFiveRoute HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "http://www.Laravel.dev/LFourRoute`
```

**error.log:**

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: www.Laravel.dev, request: "GET /moduletwo/index.php/LFiveRoute HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.22.0.5:9000", host: "www.Laravel.dev", referrer: "http://www.Laravel.dev/LFourRoute
```

**script.log:**

```
/var/www/Laravel4/public/moduletwo/index.php > GET /moduletwo/index.php/LFiveRoute HTTP/1.1
```

**Processes in Nginx Container**
***Nginx master/worker processes***

```
ps -ef | grep 'nginx'
root         1     0  0 06:15 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process     nginx -g daemon off;
www-data     7     1  0 06:16 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root        19     8  0 07:45 ?        00:00:00 grep nginx
```

***fpm Processes***

```
ps -ef | grep 'fpm'
root        21     8  0 07:47 ?        00:00:00 grep fpm
```

**Processes in PHP71 Container**
***Nginx master/worker processes***

```
none
```

***fpm Processes***

```
ps -ef | grep fpm  
root         1     0  0 06:15 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
www-data     8     1  0 06:16 ?        00:00:01 php-fpm: pool www
www-data     9     1  0 06:17 ?        00:00:01 php-fpm: pool www
www-data    10     1  0 06:22 ?        00:00:01 php-fpm: pool www
root        22    13  0 07:49 ?        00:00:00 grep fpm
```

**Docker Compose File:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name:
            Laravel-nginx
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: deploy/web.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/Laravel4
            - ./../Laravel_5:/var/www/Laravel5
            - ./app/storage/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - php71
        networks:
             Laravel_net:
                    ipv4_address: 172.22.0.2
    database:
        container_name:
            Laravel-db
        restart: always
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel_4"
        ports:
            - "3309:3306"

        networks:
             Laravel_net:
                 ipv4_address: 172.22.0.3
    redis:
        container_name:
            Laravel-redis
        image: redis:3.2
        ports:
            - "6372:6379"
        networks:
             Laravel_net:
                 ipv4_address: 172.22.0.4

    php71:
        container_name:
            Laravel-php-71
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: deploy/app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/Laravel4
            - ./../Laravel_5:/var/www/Laravel5
        links:
            - database
            - redis
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3306"
            - "DB_HOST=database"
        networks:
             Laravel_net:
                 ipv4_address: 172.22.0.5

networks:
   Laravel_net:
     driver: bridge
     ipam:
       driver: default
       config:
       - subnet: 172.22.0.0/16
         gateway: 172.22.0.1
```

**web.docker file:**

```
FROM nginx:1.10

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ADD ./deploy/vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD ./deploy/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /var/www
```

**app.docker file:**

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www
```

**nginx.conf file**

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;


events {
    # A single worker process can handle 1024 connections
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    log_format scripts '$document_root$fastcgi_script_name > $request';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/scripts.log scripts;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**vhost.conf file:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.laravel.dev;

    charset utf-8;
    sendfile off;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    index index.php;

    root /var/www/Laravel4/public;

    location ~ ^/moduletwo/(.+(?:css|js|woff|woff2|ttf))$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        alias /var/www/Laravel5/public/$1;
        #access_log off;
    }   

    #moduletwo code in laravel5
    location /moduletwo/ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        alias /var/www/Laravel5/public;
        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
        if (-d $request_filename) {
                break;
        }
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @moduletwo;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @moduletwo {
        include fastcgi_params;
        rewrite /moduletwo/(.*)$ /moduletwo/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php71:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        set $php_root /var/www/Laravel4/public;
        if ($request_uri ~ /moduletwo) {
            set $php_root /var/www/Laravel5/public;
        }
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $php_root/index.php;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 310;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

So, anybody is there? Please look into it and help me to resolve the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the output of `docker-compose exec php71 ls -alh /var/www/Laravel5`

Comment: And `docker-compose exec php71 ls -alh /var/www/`

Comment: Well, the output of both the commands shows the Laravel4 and Laravel5 directories. So, the files do exist there.

Comment: Add both the outputs to the question

Comment: Out put of `docker-compose exec php71 ls -alh /var/www/Laravel5`
total 340K
`drwxrwxr-- 17 1000 www-data 4.0K Sep 21 04:03 .`
`drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4.0K Oct  7 12:02 ..`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data  169 Apr 27 17:37 .buildpath`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data 1.1K Oct  4 10:19 .env`
`drwxrwxr--  8 1000 www-data 4.0K Oct  6 09:23 .git`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data   61 Nov 23  2015 .gitattributes`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data  130 Sep 15 06:26 .gitignore`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data  752 Apr 27 17:37 .project`

Comment: `drwxrwxr--  2 1000 www-data 4.0K Nov 25  2015 .projectKnowledge`
`drwxrwxr--  2 1000 www-data 4.0K Apr 27 17:37 .settings`
`drwxrwxr-- 34 1000 www-data 4.0K Jul 13  2016 _docs`
`drwxrwxr-- 14 1000 www-data 4.0K Jul  7 06:13 app`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data 1.6K Nov 23  2015 artisan`
`drwxrwxr--  3 1000 www-data 4.0K Oct  6 09:22 bootstrap`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data 1.5K Sep 15 06:29 composer.json`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data 182K Sep 15 06:26 composer.lock`
`drwxrwxr--  2 1000 www-data 4.0K Oct  4 15:17 config`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156158/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-mkj).

Comment: `drwxrwxr--  5 1000 www-data 4.0K Jul 13  2016 database`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data  221 Sep 15 12:08 deploy.sh`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data  503 Nov 23  2015 gulpfile.js`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data   98 Nov 23  2015 package.json`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data  777 Nov 23  2015 phpunit.xml`
`drwxrwxr--  9 1000 www-data 4.0K Jul 13  2016 public`
`-rwxrwxr--  1 1000 www-data  799 Apr 19  2016 readme.md`
`drwxrwxr--  5 1000 www-data 4.0K Jul 13  2016 resources`
`drwxrwxr--  7 1000 www-data 4.0K Sep  7 10:43 storage`
`drwxrwxr--  7 1000 www-data 4.0K Jul 13  2016 tests`